# How to wait for thread execution to complete before starting new thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python code in which I can run a maximum of 10 threads at a time due to GPU and compute limitations. I have 100 folders that I want to process and I want each thread to process one folder. Here is some sample code that I have written to achieve this.

```
def random_wait(thread_id):
    # print('Inside wait')
    rand_number = random.randint(3, 9)
    # print(f'Random number : {rand_number}')
    print(f'Thread {thread_id} waiting for {rand_number} seconds')
    time.sleep(rand_number)
    print(f'Thread {thread_id} completed execution')

if __name__=='__main__':
    total_runs = 6
    thread_limit = 3
    running_threads = list()
    for i in range(total_runs):
        print(f'Active threads : {threading.active_count()}')
        if threading.active_count() > thread_limit:
            print(f'Active thread count exceeded')
            # check if an existing thread is alive and for it to finish execution
            for running_thread in running_threads:
                if not running_thread.is_alive():
                    # Remove thread 
                    running_threads.remove(running_thread)
                    print(f'Removing thread: {running_thread}')
        else:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=random_wait, args=(i,), kwargs={})
            running_threads.append(thread)
            print(f'Starting thread : {i}')
            thread.start()
```

In this code, I am checking if the number of active threads exceeds the thread limit that I have specified, and the process refrains from creating new threads unless there's space for one more thread to be executed.

I am able to refrain the process from starting new threads. However, I lose the threads that I wanted to start and the code just ends up starting and stopping the first three threads. How can I achieve starting a new thread/processing as soon as there's space for one more? Is there a better way in which I just start 10 threads, but as soon as one thread completes, I assign it to start processing another folder?

Comment: Alternately you could use a 10 member thread pool. Use `map` with chunksize 1 and you have each thread fetch a new work item when done. No need to manage the threads yourself.

Comment: `threading.active_count()` - if some other thing you've imported is also using threads, this number will be larger than you expect.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney for the advice on using thread pool. Let me check it out and see if I can answer my own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` from the Python standard library `concurrent.futures`, it automatically manages a fixed number of threads. If you need to execute the same function with different arguments in parallel (as in a parallel for-loop), you can use the `.map()` method:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as e:
    results = e.map(work, (arg_1, arg_2, ..., arg_n))
```

If you need to schedule different work in parallel you should use the `.submit()` method:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor(10) as e:
    future_1 = e.submit(work_1, arg_1)
    future_2 = e.submit(work_2, arg_2)

result_1 = future_1.result()
result_2 = future_2.result()
```

In the second case, `.submit()` returns a `Future` object which encapsulates the asynchronous execution of the work. You should store that future and get the result when needed. Note that the context manager (`with` statement) ensures that the `.shutdown()` method is call before leaving it, so all works are done after this point.

Comment: Thanks @Louis! Works perfectly!